# Angularjs two way data binding on ng-repeat with directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

**What I am trying to achieve:** trigger an angular js directive on a jquery ui event which in turn calls a method in the controller, which adds a value in an array which should appear in the view because of the two way data binding.

**What does not work:** the value is properly added in the array but the view is not updated

**HTML**

```
<li id="collection_{{$index+1}}" class="collection" ng-repeat="collection in column | filter:avoidUndefined" ng-controller="collectionController" ng-model="collection">
    <h1 class="collection-title"> {{ collection.title }}</h1>
    <ul class="bookmarks sortable droppable" droppable=".draggable" sortable=".bookmarks.sortable">
        <li class="bookmark" ng-repeat="bookmark in collection.bookmarks">
            <a class="bookmark-link bookmark-{{bookmark.id}}" href="{{bookmark.url}}">{{bookmark.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
directives.directive('droppable',function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope,el,attrs){
        el.droppable({
            accept: attrs.droppable,
            drop: function( event, ui ) {            
                var url = $(ui.helper).text();
                scope.addBookmark(null, url, url);
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            },
...
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.addBookmark = function (id, title, url){
    if (id == null) {
        ...
    }
    var bookmark = {
        'id': id,
        'title': title,
        'url': url,
        'type': 'bookmark'
    };
    $scope.collection.bookmarks.push(bookmark);
};
```

`$scope.collection.bookmarks` is updated properly but the view stays the same. If I call the same `addBookmark` function directly with a normal button it works.

Comment: have you tried putting a scope.$apply(); at the end of your link function?

Comment: that produces the error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Comment: Your directive is doing something it should not... Directives Should not call controller methods

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier I would say that it solves your problem. However it is not right way to do it.

Comment: So what would be a proper way ? should I use $emit instead of calling directly a function ?

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier correct $emit looks more appropriate. I just added some of ideas I think will will lead to a better approach. I hope they help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your drop-callback in `$apply`:

```
directives.directive('droppable',function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope,el,attrs){
        el.droppable({
            accept: attrs.droppable,
            drop: function( event, ui ) {            
                scope.$apply(function(scope){
                    var url = $(ui.helper).text();
                    scope.addBookmark(null, url, url);
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                });
            },
...
```

Comment: It works, and I put $(this).removeClass('ui-state-highlight') outside scope.$apply

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use `$emit` instead of calling a method of the controller directly in your directive.

Directives should be always independent components, if inside the directive there is a call to  a method from a controller(outside the directive) this will create a dependency between my directive and the controller and of course this will force one not being able to exist without the other.

If I would have to apply a design principle to a directive it will be the S in SOLID, Single responsibility principle. Directives should be able to encapsulate and work independently.

I would probably try this on my directive: `scope.$emit("UrlChanged", url);`

Something like this:

```
directives.directive('droppable',function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope,el,attrs){
        el.droppable({
            accept: attrs.droppable,
            drop: function( event, ui ) {            
                    var url = $(ui.helper).text();
                    scope.$emit("UrlChanged", url);
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');

            },
```

On my controller:

```
$scope.$on("UrlChanged", function(event, url){
   ... //your has changed.    
});
```

Comment: Despite I like this recommendation, in this way I am back to the initial problem. Should I wrap your $emit inside a scope.$apply ?

Comment: Without $apply the view is not updated, only the model